# Should I write a conference proceeding of my master's thesis work so far?

Tags: masters, conference

I'll be attending to a conference and do a poster presentation of my master's thesis work so far. What I'm concerned of is that my tutor wants me to also wirte a short report to be submitted as a conference proceeding.

What I've done so far is nothing new. I've just applied already existing theory and numerical codes to specific cases... which should be easy to do for people that already understands the topic and has technical expertise with the numerical code I'm using (I know there is people that do have it).

Should I just write the report or talk it with my tutor?

Comment: Likely you should _both_: start on the report, if just to focus your thinking, _and_ talk it over with your tutor. I don't know how you use the term tutor, though. If it is a person with some authority over your progress, then that advice should almost always be taken. If it is just a grad assistant assigned to help you, then advice from farther up the food chain would be valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What I've done so far is nothing new. I've just applied already existing theory and numerical codes to specific cases...*

I don't know what subject you are in but that **is** new. You have taken an already known theory and applied it to something else, even if that is a specific case of something. I am assuming you got results from applying this case, in which talk about those lots in your evaluation.

*which should be easy to do for people that already understands the topic and has technical expertise with the numerical code I'm using*

Which means it was probably overlooked. Do not assume that if something is easy to do and no one has done it that it is not important. There could be many reasons why they chose to follow a different path of research, you cannot second guess why.

--
My Opinion:

I am a first year PhD in CS, I have struggled many times that what I am doing would be easy, simple, obvious to others to do. One thing that keeps me going is this quote: "standing on the shoulders of giants".

My view on the report; include the following two aspects:

- Your contributions, why is it different, if you have applied it to specific cases say that as that is what makes it unique.
- Evaluation. This is where you can prove you are different, that even though you "only" took a theory and applied it elsewhere you can show it worked (or maybe didn't).

In all good luck with your conference and poster, and enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you submit a poster to a conference you have an auxiliary, small (typically 4 pages), paper that puts what is said in the poster in a more formal and verbal way. This is due to the majority of conferences does not compile the posters in proceedings, but only papers.

So, when writing a short paper you mostly have to focus on your *positional view*: giving a summary of what you did until now, what you expect to do, and what will be the outcomes of your research.